# JavaFX: How to bind text field "style property" to text property matching some pattern

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

In my application I have a screen with three fields which I need to validate, and a Save button.

I bind save button "disable property" to fields' "text property" matching some pattern (simplified patterns in this example, doesn't matter):

```
public void initialize(){
    saveNetworkBtn.disableProperty()
            .bind(textPropertyBindingPattern(ipInp, Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}"))
                    .or(textPropertyBindingPattern(subnetInp, Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}")))
                    .or(textPropertyBindingPattern(gatewayInp, Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}"))));
}

private BooleanBinding textPropertyBindingPattern(TextField textField, Pattern pattern ) {
    return Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
            !pattern.matcher(textField.getText()).matches(), textField.textProperty());
}
```

So that save button is locked until all values are correct:[image]

But I need to highlight incorrect fields also with some red border like

```
-fx-border-color: red;
```

[image]

My main goal is to handle this in one place instead of adding several listeners. 
Is it possible to bing this somehow in the code above or I need to add listeners to each field?

Comment: I would recommend binding each property individually. So yes, bind the field's border or style property to its text. If you have many such fields, subclass `TextField` and add this binding behavior directly to it. Then you won't have to bind each field separately.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a listener to binding, which adds a style to received text field:

```
private BooleanBinding textPropertyBindingPattern(TextField textField, Pattern pattern) {
    BooleanBinding binding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
            !pattern.matcher(textField.getText()).matches(), textField.textProperty());

    applyValidationClass(textField, binding.get());

    binding.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        applyValidationClass(textField, newValue);
    });
    return binding ;
}

private void applyValidationClass(TextField textField, boolean isInvalid) {
    textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("incorrect-value"), isInvalid);
}
```

and 'incorrect-value' described in CSS file:

```
TextField:incorrect-value {
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

Visualisation: https://www.screencast.com/t/4NKEjjopvaE7